# Merkle tree whitelisting

Tags: javascript, react, merkle-patricia-tries

Ive been trying to whitelist huge amount of addresses with merkle tree.

Here is my json:

```json
[
"0xb860BA0E67C8......5ca4b4720d49F549AE8faA",
"0xaF019d749865.......f044C1A534e1eC9F0D353",
"0x45267399dFF.......5FD12B06Ce773945E7A6C4",
"0x45267323dFF.......5FD12406Cs743243E7A6C4",
"0xb860BA0E47C.......5ca4s4720d49F549AE8faA"
]
```

Here is my js:

```js
const { MerkleTree } = require('merkletreejs');
const whitelist = require('./whitelist.json');
const keccak256 = require('keccak256');


const leafNodes = whitelist.map(addr => keccak256(addr));
const tree = new MerkleTree(leafNodes, keccak256, { softPairs: true });
const root = tree.getHexRoot();
    
    
const claimingAdress = leafNodes[0];
const proof = tree.getHexProof(claimingAdress);
    
console.log(tree.verify(proof, leafNodes, root));
```

When I run this I get `"TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "list[1]" argument must be an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array."`

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

**edit:** I changed the code a bit and Im getting proof array with 3 elements.

New code:

```js
const { MerkleTree } = require('merkletreejs');
const keccak256 = require('keccak256');
const whitelistAddresses = require('./whitelist.json');
    
const leafNodes = whitelistAddresses.map(addr => keccak256(addr));
const tree = new MerkleTree(leafNodes, keccak256, { sortPairs: true});
    
const root = tree.getRoot();
    
const claimingAccount = leafNodes[0];
const hexProof = tree.getHexProof(claimingAccount);
```

Is proof sent to smart contract as an array? or do I have to do something before I send?

**edit 2:** Yes proof sent as an array and it works.

Comment: What commands to you use to run this in visual, I did npm install merkletree and npm install keccak256 but unsure what command I use to run the final thing? Cheers

Comment: If you have node js installed you can run it with: "node scriptname.js" Just make sure that you are in same directory with that script.

Comment: Here is a link to Using Merkel tree for whitelisting https://medium.com/@ItsCuzzo/using-merkle-trees-for-nft-whitelists-523b58ada3f9 I am supprised you haven't found this.